# once selected hide Radio buttons and display selected value in new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RM5o.png)once user clicks on a particular radio button in a list,then the entire radio buttons list must hide and the selected radio button value must be displayed in a new div, something like shown in "try demo" button in right bottom page of " https://collect.chat/ "  website

```
<p class="chat-message">Which course you want to choose?
<label class="container">Course 1
<input type="radio" name="co1"value="course 1">
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

<label class="container">Course 2
<input type="radio"  name="co2"value="course 2">
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

<label class="container">Course 3
<input type="radio"  name="co3"value="course 3">
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

<label class="container">Course 4
<input type="radio"  name="co4"value="course 4">
<span class="checkmark"></span></label> 

</p>

<div class="chat self">
<p class="chat-message"><span id="result"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
  document.mainForm.onclick = function()
  {
  var radVal = document.mainForm.rads.value;
  result.innerHTML = 'The course i want is'+radVal;
  }
 </script>
```

I expect the radio buttons must hide once selected and selected value must display in a separate div

[As show in the image the radio buttons disappear once they are selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOdEE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a clean jQuery solution. You have to give the radio buttons a unique Id in order to hide it.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="chat-message" id="course-picker">Which course you want to choose?
<label class="container">Course 1
<input type="radio" name="co1"value="course 1">
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

<label class="container">Course 2
<input type="radio"  name="co2"value="course 2">
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

<label class="container">Course 3
<input type="radio"  name="co3"value="course 3">
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

<label class="container">Course 4
<input type="radio"  name="co4"value="course 4">
<span class="checkmark"></span></label> 

</p>

<div class="chat self">
<p class="chat-message"><span id="result"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(':radio').click(function () {
    $("#result").text(this.value);
    $("#course-picker").hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function show(str){
                document.getElementById('sh2').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('sh1').style.display = 'block';
            }
            function show2(sign){
                document.getElementById('sh2').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('sh1').style.display = 'none';
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="r1" id="e1" onchange="show2()"/>&nbsp;I Am New User&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="r1" onchange="show(this.value)"/>&nbsp;Existing Member
        </p>
        <div id="sh1">Hello There !!</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div id="sh2" style="display:none;">Hey Watz up !!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but i want the radio buttons to disappear once selected

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try like this.

```
<p class="chat-message">Which course you want to choose?
<label class="container">Course 1
<input type="radio" name="co1"value="course 1">
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

<label class="container">Course 2
<input type="radio"  name="co2"value="course 2">
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

<label class="container">Course 3
<input type="radio"  name="co3"value="course 3">
<span class="checkmark"></span></label>

<label class="container">Course 4
<input type="radio"  name="co4"value="course 4">
<span class="checkmark"></span></label> 

</p>

<div class="chat self" style="display: none;"->
<p class="chat-message"><span id="result"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
  document.mainForm.onclick = function()
  {
    var radVal = document.mainForm.rads.value;
    result.innerHTML = 'The course i want is'+radVal;
    $(".chat-message").hide();
    $(".chat.self").show();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to try this with vanilla JS , on click of the radio options value of the label should be appended to results div and the question div should be hidden.

please check the below code snippet, hope it helps.

```js
var course_radio = document.querySelectorAll("[type='radio']")

function handleSelection() {
    var question_text = this.closest(".chat-message").children[0].innerHTML;

    this.closest('.chat-message').style.display = "none"
    var question = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode(question_text);
    question.appendChild(node);

    var answer = document.createElement("p");
    var ans_node = document.createTextNode(this.value);
    answer.appendChild(ans_node);


    document.getElementById("result").appendChild(question);
    document.getElementById("result").appendChild(answer);
}

for (var i = 0; i < course_radio.length; i++) {
    course_radio[i].addEventListener('click', handleSelection);
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-message">
    <p class="chat-question">Which course you want to choose?</p>
    <label class="container">Course 1
        <input type="radio" name="co1" value="course 1" class="course-checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span></label>

    <label class="container">Course 2
        <input type="radio" name="co2" value="course 2" class="course-checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span></label>

    <label class="container">Course 3
        <input type="radio" name="co3" value="course 3" class="course-checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span></label>

    <label class="container">Course 4
        <input type="radio" name="co4" value="course 4" class="course-checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span></label>

</div>

<div class="chat self">
    <p class="chat-message"><span id="result"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, the radio buttons are disappearing.But i want the question be there "Which course you want to choose" and only radio buttons must be hidden. and  how can i open new div (chat self) in which the selected radio button can be shown

Comment: @HasheemIshaq have edited my answer to populate the question and its selected answer in the results div.

Have tried to keep the code verbose , please go though and i am sure you will be able to make further changes to complete the project.

All the best